# why this mysql insert is failing in java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
try
         {
            String sql="INSERT INTO `task`(`task`,`time`) VALUES(?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt=this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, this.task);
            stmt.setInt(2, this.time);
            //stmt.
            Boolean res= stmt.execute(sql);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.err.println(e);
         }
```

ERROR:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use

```
stmt.execute(sql);
```

use

```
stmt.execute();
```

to execute your `PreparedStatement`.

The first one you are using tries to execute the given string, which is obviously not what you want to execute due to the placeholder `'?'` values in it (it is a method of the `java.sql.Statement` interface).

The second one is a method from `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and executes the `PreparedStatement` with the values you entered through the `setXXX()` methods.

---

Also, in your case you don't need ticks in your string, you can just write

```
String sql="INSERT INTO task(task,time) VALUES(?,?)";
```

Comment: MySql expects for String 'value' not value, so try to put ? into quotes.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov: No, don't need it, `PreparedStatement` takes care of that for you.

Comment: @jlordo With JDBC you could also need backticks, but only where it is actually required (just like with all other MySQL uses, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: @jlordo, oh ok. Will put a note to myself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel should we always use backticks then in the query String, or only if it is a reserved word (eg: event)?

Comment: @theyuv You only need it with reserved words, just like where other uses of MySQL requires backticks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. So would you recommend that they be avoided in general? I just find it annoying to have to think when writing my queries if I'm typing a reserved word or not. So is it recommended to stay away from them when naming tables, columns, etc.?

Comment: @theyuv Use what works for you and your team. Both have their pros and cons (eg always quoting avoids issues with things becoming reserved, while - in my opinion - it hurts readability), but at the end of the day it is just an opinion, so agreement within your team is more important than what some random stranger on the internet thinks.